# For loop with time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x

im a beginner at python and i've come across what is probably a simple problem.
I want the code below to print the `"."` x times, each .100 of a second after each other. This is what ive got, but it just prints it all at once after x * .100 seconds. It would also help if you could redirect me to something that explains why it dosnt work or if you explained why it dosnt work.

```
import time
for i in range(x):
    print(".", end="")
    time.sleep(.100)
```

Thanks in advance.

PS. If the code is completely wrong please say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just printing doesn't mean that the content is flushed - i.e. it can still be in a buffer in your terminal or execution environment.

You can append `flush=True` to the arguments to `print` in python3 to make it flush the output as well:

```
import time

for i in range(x):
    print(".", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(.100)
```